# Select Query to MS-Access works internally, but doesn't display when called in ASP.NET

Tags: c#, asp.net, ms-access

I select using this following query:

```
//what 
        string command = "SELECT DISTINCT AAopenstaande_orders.debnr, AAopenstaande_orders.naam as debnaam, AAopenstaande_orders.ordernr as ordernr, AAopenstaande_orders.artcode as artcode, AAopenstaande_orders.oms45 as omschrijving, AAopenstaande_orders.televeren as aantal, AAopenstaande_orders.afldat as afldat, AAopenstaande_orders.selcode as selcode, AAopenstaande_orders.kanban as instructie, AAopenstaande_orders.prodorder as prodorder, AAopenstaande_orders.status, personeel.medewerker as medewerker, processtap.processtap AS processtap, po_plus_maxprodstap.datum as datum, po_plus_maxprodstap.tijd as tijd, AAopenstaande_orders.regel, [aaopenstaande_orders].[ordernr] & Trim([aaopenstaande_orders].[regel]) AS sleutel, unieksubprodfilter.subaanw as subaanw";
//from where

        command += " FROM(((AAopenstaande_orders LEFT JOIN po_plus_maxprodstap ON AAopenstaande_orders.prodorder = po_plus_maxprodstap.productieorder) LEFT JOIN personeel ON po_plus_maxprodstap.personeelsnummer = personeel.personeelsnummer) LEFT JOIN processtap ON po_plus_maxprodstap.IDprocesstap = processtap.IDprocesstap) LEFT JOIN unieksubprodfilter ON AAopenstaande_orders.prodorder = unieksubprodfilter.Expr1 ";
```

When I put this query into access directly (- the C# stuff ofc), I get exactly the table I want. But when I run this in my ASP.NET program, and call the data with `<%# Eval("datum","{0:d}")%>'>` or `'<%# ((DataRowView)Container.DataItem)["datum"] %>'>` **most** of the data shows up.  Except that last bit, `subaanw`, that column is completely empty. It Should have a 'ja' on rows where the `unieksubprodfilter` has that prodorder, but instead they are all NULL. I thought maybe it's because `unieksubprodfilter` is a Query in access and not a straight up table. But you'd think the Select statement would crash if it didn't work. instead it just doesn't show the data I need.

Sorry about the Dutch in some of the code, I wasn't the one that made those parts.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I Figured it out, the Jet database engine doesn't recognise * as a wildcard character, even though Access does. Changing the wildcard to % fixed the table.